# I can't properly authorize my Python web app to access Google API

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm using google api to integrate some google sheet data into my app. I have a server where I can only connect via SSH, as it has no user interface. When I start my app, it gives me this message:

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=XXX-XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A57731%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets.readonly&state=XXX&access_type=offline
```

Since I don't have a UI on my server, how can I authorize the application? I've just started using the google api, I still can't figure out how to go about it.

The only thing I've tried and that works is to run the code from a windows pc for example and then transfer the token.json file to my server. The problem is that after 30 days it expires and I have to redo the whole procedure again.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

import os.path

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

# The ID of a sample spreadsheet.
SPREADSHEET_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# Google API credentials
googleCredentials = None

def main():
    print("Loadin google API...")
    global googleCredentials
    if os.path.exists("./json/token.json"):
        googleCredentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("./json/token.json", SCOPES)

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not googleCredentials or not googleCredentials.valid:
        if googleCredentials and googleCredentials.expired and googleCredentials.refresh_token:
            googleCredentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("./json/credentials.json", SCOPES)
            googleCredentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open("./json/token.json", 'w') as token:
            token.write(googleCredentials.to_json())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code.    I suspect you are using code designed for an installed application when you need to be using code designed for a web application

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Done, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing I've tried and that works is to run the code from a windows pc for example and then transfer the token.json file to my server. The problem is that after 30 days it expires and I have to redo the whole procedure again.

It sounds like you have done exactly what you should do.   The token.json file should be just fine stored on your machine.  The question is why is your refresh token expireing.

If your app is still in the testing phase the refresh token will expire after seven days.  The solution for that is to go to google cloud console for your app then to the Oauth2 consent screen and set it to production the next time you create a refresh token it will not expire.

[image]

I'm a bit curious as to why you say this lasts 30 days which me think you might be getting a new refresh token back every time it refreshes your access token and its not being saved but that's not supposed to happen with the python library its supposed to handle that I will have to test it.

If you are only connecting to this single sheet, Have you considered using a service account instead?

## service account

Just make sure to share the sheet with the service accounts email address, just like you would any other user via the google drive web app.  It will have access to your sheet without any user intervension.

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    KEYFILE,
    scopes=SCOPES,
)
```

- [How to create service account credentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A&)
- [Should you be using a Google service account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTTTtwb7x7g)

## Token.json explained

Below is the contense of a token.json file, this is exactly what an authorization server returns to you as the final step in the oauth flow.

The first on Token is actually your access token, the expire says when that access token will expire.  When your code loads it will check if the access token in the file has expired if it has it will request a new one using the refresh token.   look for: `googleCredentials.expired`

```
{
  "token": "[Redacted Access Token]",
  "refresh_token": "[Redacted refresh Token]",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "client_id": "[REDACTED]",
  "client_secret": "[REDACTED]",
  "scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
  ],
  "expiry": "2022-10-25T12:06:40.318779Z"
}
```

Comment: I have switched to "In production" status. I restarted the code on my Windows pc and than I have uploaded the new `token.json` file on my server were my app is hosted. The new `token.json` file look like this: `{"token": "...", "refresh_token": "1//...", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "client_id": "...", "client_secret": "...", "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"], "expiry": "2023-02-07T22:04:17.884946Z"}`. Is it normal that there is the `expiry` parameter? Does this mean that the token will expiry again?

Comment: No check update, the expire is associated with the access token not the  rrefresh token.

Comment: on my side, i am only able to publish the app which calls for making a video of how to use it and other bonanzay silly requests... is there another way or G forces you to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here incase it helps someone else.

I came across the same issue and while looking for a solution tried something else that also worked.

1. Install xming x server on windows machine
2. ssh into machine with no GUI with putty and X11 forwarding enabled
3. Run app in ssh session and see an xming browser session appear on the windows machine to complete the authorisation.